# Elixir/Phoenix New Project Comeonin.Bcrypt is unavailable

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, bcrypt

First, I am developing in Windows 10. I run `vcvarsall.bat amd64` before each compile. I am using:

- Elixir 1.4.2
- Phoenix v1.2.1

I started a brand new project, made a users table, and everything was working fine. The I added comeonin to hash the pw and I can no longer create users. I get an error page saying:
 `function Comeonin.Bcrypt.hashpwsalt/1 is undefined (module Comeonin.Bcrypt is not available)`

Here is the code from the relevant files:

***Mix.exs***

```
# mix.exs

 ...

  def application do
    [mod: {PollarAppV2, []},
     applications: [:phoenix, :phoenix_pubsub, :phoenix_html, :cowboy, :logger, :gettext,
     :phoenix_ecto, :postgrex, :comeonin, :timex]]
  end

 ...

  defp deps do
    [{:phoenix, "~> 1.2.1"},
     {:phoenix_pubsub, "~> 1.0"},
     {:phoenix_ecto, "~> 3.0"},
     {:postgrex, ">= 0.0.0"},
     {:phoenix_html, "~> 2.6"},
     {:phoenix_live_reload, "~> 1.0", only: :dev},
     {:gettext, "~> 0.11"},
     {:cowboy, "~> 1.0"},
     {:comeonin, "~> 3.0"},
     {:timex, "~> 3.0"}]
  end

 ...
```

***User.ex***

```
# user.ex

...

  defp generate_password_hash(changeset) do
    case changeset do
      %Ecto.Changeset{valid?: true, changes: %{password: password}} ->
        put_change(changeset, :encrypted_password, Comeonin.Bcrypt.hashpwsalt(password))
      _ ->
        changeset
    end
  end
```

When I try to save a user, which invokes generate_password_hash, I get this error:

***Console***

```
[warn] The on_load function for module Elixir.Comeonin.Bcrypt returned { :error,
 {:load_failed,
  'Failed to load NIF library c:/code/phoenix/pollar_app_v2/_build/dev/lib/comeonin/priv/bcrypt_nif: \'Unspecified error\''}}

[info] Sent 500 in 16ms
[error] #PID<0.430.0> running PollarAppV2.Endpoint terminated
Server: localhost:4000 (http)
Request: POST /users
** (exit) an exception was raised:
    ** (UndefinedFunctionError) function Comeonin.Bcrypt.hashpwsalt/1 is 
undefined (module Comeonin.Bcrypt is not available)
        (comeonin) Comeonin.Bcrypt.hashpwsalt("asdfasdf")
        (pollar_app_v2) web/models/user.ex:40: PollarAppV2.User.generate_password_hash/1
        (pollar_app_v2) web/controllers/user_controller.ex:17: PollarAppV2.UserController.create/2
        (pollar_app_v2) web/controllers/user_controller.ex:1: PollarAppV2.UserController.action/2
        (pollar_app_v2) web/controllers/user_controller.ex:1: PollarAppV2.UserController.phoenix_controller_pipeline/2
        (pollar_app_v2) lib/pollar_app_v2/endpoint.ex:1: PollarAppV2.Endpoint.instrument/4
        (pollar_app_v2) lib/phoenix/router.ex:261: PollarAppV2.Router.dispatch/2
        (pollar_app_v2) web/router.ex:1: PollarAppV2.Router.do_call/2
        (pollar_app_v2) lib/pollar_app_v2/endpoint.ex:1: PollarAppV2.Endpoint.phoenix_pipeline/1
        (pollar_app_v2) lib/plug/debugger.ex:123: PollarAppV2.Endpoint."call 
(overridable 3)"/2  
        (pollar_app_v2) lib/pollar_app_v2/endpoint.ex:1:  PollarAppV2.Endpoint.call/2
        (plug) lib/plug/adapters/cowboy/handler.ex:15: Plug.Adapters.Cowboy.Handler.upgrade/4
        (cowboy) 
        c:/code/phoenix/pollar_app_v2/deps/cowboy/src/cowboy_protocol.erl:442: :cowboy_protocol.execute/4
```

I have run `mix deps.clean --all`, `mix deps.update --all`, `mix deps.compile`, `mix compile`, etc. all multiple times. It never indicates that the nif files are not compiling, and I can see the files in the correct place in the file structure, but I cannot get access to Bcrypt within the application. Any ideas as to how to fix this?

Comment: Did you also try `mix clean` (or manually removing `_build`)?

Comment: Yes, I have done both of those multiple times, as well. I just cannot seem to find anything that works.

Comment: Which version of Comeonin?

Comment: Also do you have mingw installed or not?

Comment: Comeonin 3.0.2 and yes I have mingw. What's really bothering me now, is if I keep creating new projects, doing the exact same process over and over, sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't. As in, some projects it never works, and others it does. It's so frustrating.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I runned into the same issue. From [the repo's readme](https://github.com/riverrun/comeonin), it is said you need of add the correct library for your choosen algorithm. In your case :

`{:bcrypt_elixir, "~> 1.0"},`

It solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

This is due to from cross-platform issues with Bcrypt, which must be compiled from C. Basically, 64-bit Erlang isn't working with a 32-bit dll.

The first step to resolve it is to install Visual Studio Community edition 2015 or higher. Then install the C++ build tools for it.

Next, open up a "Developer Command Prompt for VS2015". It will open a prompt in its current directory (e.g. `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\`).

In its `VC` sub-directory, there should be a file called `vcvarsall.bat`. `cd` into that directory and pass the vcvarsall.bat command an argument to set your compilation target to 64-bit:

```
cd vc
vcvarsall.bat amd64
```

Next, go back to your directory with your Phoenix and clean out whatever you've built for comeonin and recompile.

```
cd c:\path to\my phoenix project
mix deps.clean comeonin
mix deps.update comeonin
mix deps.compile comeonin
```

And then you *should* have a working Bcrypt NIF for your platform.